# How to name network adapters created with virt-install?

Tags: linux, libvirt, network-interface

In order to test preseeded installation, I want to create a virtual machine as close as possible to an actual server I use in production. The server has two network adapters: `p1p1` and `p2p1`.

When creating a virtual machine with:

```
virt-install \
    --connect=qemu:///system \
    ...
    --network=bridge:br0 \
    --network=bridge:br0 \
    ...
```

the network adapters are called `eth0` and `eth1`.

Is there a way to name them `p1p1` and `p2p1` before installing an OS?

Comment: What distro are you using? The names of the devices for network are often times controlled by dbus.

Comment: @slm: `virt-install` is executed on Ubuntu desktop 14.04. Also, if it matters, OSes installed on the newly created virtual machine are either Debian 7.5.0 or Ubuntu server 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define and start the networks in libvirt before.

1. Start by creating a XML file [describing your network](http://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html).
2. Enter in libvirt console, [define the network](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html-single/#sect-net-define) using the XML file and then [activate it](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html-single/#sect-net-start). You also might [mark as autostart](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html-single/#sect-net-autostart).

   ```
   net-define example.xml
   net-autostart vbr0
   net-start vbr0
   ```
3. The last step is create your VM adding the network previously added.

   ```
   --network=<network-name>
   ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer the OP's question, which seems to have been: how to rename eth0 and eth1 into p1p1 and p2p1 in the guest?